# azure pipeline maven release

Tags: maven, azure-devops, maven-plugin

I am writing my first pipeline and if some one can please help. I have issue with creating a release version jar.

2 pom.xml (1 in master branch and 1 in development branch )

master branch pom.xml has release plugin defined
development branch pom.xml has compile and release plugin defined .

apart from that both pom.xml is same

When i run the pipeline from development branch it checkout development pom.xml and working absolutely fine like create snapshot.jar , (i use mvn clean install here )

When i run the pipeline from master branch it checkout master pom.xml and giving parent pom not solvable issue , (i use mvn release:prepare release:perform here )

````
[Thread-5] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor - [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.xxxxxxxxx: com.xxxxx-parent:pom:1.0.0 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 5, column 13
[Thread-5] INFO org.apache.maven.shared.release.exec.InvokerMavenExecutor -  @ ```


the strange part is when i use mvn clean install like in development in master branch code , it gives no problem but it is releasing snapshot.jar .

My release plugin has some issue , i dont know what 

my goal is when running from development branch it should create snapshot.jar and when i run from master branch it should create <application>_release_version.jar .

any help much appreciated
````

```
  - task: ArtifactoryMaven@2
    inputs:
#      mavenPomFile: '${{ parameters.layer }}/pom.xml'
#      goals: 'clean install'
      mavenPomFile: 'pom_azure.xml'
      goals: 'release:prepare release:perform'
     
#      options: '-U -DlocalCheckout=true -Dresume=false --batch-mode -Dtag=v1.0.0 -DreleaseVersion=1.0.0 -DdevelopmentVersion=2.0.0-SNAPSHOT Dusername=Personal%20Access%20Token -Dpassword=11c9decb81845396ecbd4bc8f09521e73077bbbf'
      options: '-B -DpushChanges=false -DlocalCheckout=true -Dresume=false --batch-mode  -DreleaseVersion=${{ parameters.release_ver }} -DdevelopmentVersion=${{ parameters.release_ver }}-SNAPSHOT'
      artifactoryResolverService: 'xxxx'
      targetResolveReleaseRepo: 'aaa-maven-virtual'
      targetResolveSnapshotRepo: 'aaa-maven-virtual'
      artifactoryDeployService: 'xxxx'
      targetDeployReleaseRepo: 'aaa-main-maven-releases'
      targetDeploySnapshotRepo: 'bbb-main-maven-snapshots'
      collectBuildInfo: true
      buildName: '$(Build.DefinitionName)'
      buildNumber: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    displayName: 'Maven Release'
```

Comment: I have no clue how to solve this issue for past few days ,the current jenkins pipeline using the same 2 pom.xml (master, development ) is exactly doing what is expected above . What all i am trying to do is mimic jenkins jobs , thanks

Comment: First can you explain show why you need two different pom files ?

Comment: Hi ,that is how the current setup in jenkins , i am trying to mimic that in azure devops , the developer execute the pipeline for dev/test without release version so they just create snapshot version jar of application and  my team will use the same pipeline to deploy in prod in which we give release version as input , so it should create application_version_name.jar (so 2 pom one for developers in devlop branch and one for us in master branch ) , so 2 pom ,thanks

Comment: So `application_version_name.jar` this is naming conventions which is not supported by Maven so it would be easier to follow naming conventions in Maven so you don't have to do configuration(how?) furthermore where is the version coming from ? From your pom or from outside? If so you could add a parameter to `release:prepare -DreleaseVersion=...` etc. Can you show your pom files?

Comment: hi , as you can see i already have this in my option command in the above code , -DreleaseVersion=${{ parameters.release_ver }}  .. The release version is the input i give when running the pipeline ..  xxxx-restapi-order-service-1.0.9.jar (this is the jar file name that is currently in jfrog when running the job from jenkins)

Comment: the pom file is bit big not sure how to add here , sorry my bad i dont want the jar with this name convention application_version_name.jar but like xxx-restapi-order-service-1.0.9.jar  (1.0.9) is passed as input from my pipeline , thanks